# Laravel & Laravel Forge returns "MaxAttemptsExceededException:" even when tries are set at 1

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd, laravel-forge

My error log is getting filled with this useless text, I have set my job to only try once and the time out to 0 because the jobs can be really long and it depends on the user.

So the job has tries set at 1 timeout at 0, on laravel forge I have set my worker to have max tries at 1 and timeout 0, and still it gives me this error in the logs:

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out. in /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:385
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(311): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts('beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob), 1)
#1 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(267): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#2 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(113): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob), 'beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#3 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('beanstalkd', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#4 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(84): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('beanstalkd', 'default')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#6 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#8 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#9 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#10 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#11 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(240): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#12 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#13 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(860): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(218): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /home/forge/Altpocket.io/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 {main}
```

Here is my job:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Events\PushEvent;
use Cache;

class ImportBittrex implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     protected $userid;
     protected $withdraws;
     protected $cachekey;

     public $tries = 1;
     public $timeout = 0;


    public function __construct($userid, $withdraws)
    {
        $this->userid = $userid;
        $this->withdraws = $withdraws;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      $this->cachekey = 'Import-Bittrex2'.$this->userid;
      if(Cache::get($this->cachekey) !== null) {
         event(new PushEvent('You already have an import running!', 'error', $this->userid));
         return $this->userid;
     }
      Cache::put($this->cachekey, 1, 5);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->importDepositsB($this->userid);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->importTradesB($this->userid);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->insertBuysB($this->userid);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->importWithdrawsB($this->userid, $this->withdraws);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->insertSellsB($this->userid);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->importBalancesB($this->userid);
      app('App\Http\Controllers\ImportController')->safeBittrexCheck($this->userid);
      Cache::forget('investments'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('b_investments'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('deposits'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('withdraws'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('balances'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('balances-summed'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('deposits'.$this->userid);
      Cache::forget('withdraws'.$this->userid);

      Cache::forget($this->cachekey);
    }
}
```

Here is my worker on laravel forge:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0QZw.png

What is wrong here? Why does this keep happening.

Basicially in the first function run in the job it will check if the user has a valid api key combination and if it doesnt it catches it and throws an error like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iv4Y.png

Please help me I'm losing my mind.

Comment: So you are invoking a controller inside a queue. You are basically bootstrapping the framework every time you are calling a controller function. This is a really bad approach to working with queues.

Comment: @RazaMehdi, Yeah, what is bad about that? I got recommended to use controllers in jobs. We have a really advanced import function on our application.

Comment: Whatever code you have inside those functions can be refactored to separate classes & methods to be used globally. However recommended you to use controllers inside a Laravel queue was bad advice. This is why the error you are facing is happening.

Comment: @RazaMehdi So should I just put all the code inside the job?

Comment: @Edwin I imagine you got this working already since I use your site and waiting for Binance.. lol. In answer to your question though, Create a Import class and use that calling the methods like you are doing. You won't bootstrap the whole framework that way. Also, if you are running this in queue, try using daemon worker if you aren't already. If you have similar code between different exchanges, create an abstract Import class, then extend from that for each exchange. Like PolinexImport extends Import.